# Composite primary key as foreign key MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, rdbms, composite-primary-key

I have a table

```
TABLE PARTECIPATION
(PARTY_ID INT,
GUEST ...
PRIMARY KEY(PARTY_ID, GUEST)
FOREIGN KEY(PARTY_ID) REFERENCES PARTY(ID)
FOREIGN KEY(GUEST) REFERENCES GUEST(GUEST)
)
```

And a table of guests

```
TABLE GUEST
(NAME VARCHAR(20),
SURNAME VARCHAR(20),
AGE INT,

PRIMARY KEY(NAME, SURNAME)
)
```

Now, how can I set the GUEST element of PARTECIPATION as FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES to GUEST TABLE?

Should I create a column into GUEST named, idk, ID and set this one as primary key? Or can I do something like this:

```
TABLE PARTECIPATION
(PARTY_ID INT,
GUEST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
GUEST_SURNAME VARCHAR(20)
PRIMARY KEY(PARTY_ID, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_SURNAME)
FOREIGN KEY(PARTY_ID) REFERENCES PARTY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(GUEST_NAME) REFERENCES GUEST(NAME),
FOREIGN KEY(GUEST_SURNAME) REFERENCES GUEST(SURNAME))
```

Comment: Yes, you can reference multi field pks in a foreign key, but names do not make a good pk. Just think: what happens if two John Smith tried to register? So, in this particular case you should create a separate guest_id field, make that the unique id and reference that in the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key must have the same number of columns, in the same order, as the primary key it references. This means you must put multiple columns into one foreign key definition, if the PK has multiple columns.

```
TABLE PARTECIPATION
(PARTY_ID INT,
GUEST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
GUEST_SURNAME VARCHAR(20)
PRIMARY KEY(PARTY_ID, GUEST_NAME, GUEST_SURNAME)
FOREIGN KEY(PARTY_ID) REFERENCES PARTY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(GUEST_NAME, GUEST_SURNAME) REFERENCES GUEST(NAME, SURNAME))
```

Comment: Thank you! So, if a foreign key references to a composite primary key, I must declare it in a single foreign key definition right? As you just wrote? I know that's the worst example I could create, but I need to understand the concept

Comment: Yes, as I just wrote.